# wget: Checking for file timestamp and overwriting

Tags: wget

How can I get `wget` to do this:

Download a file from a location say `x`, only if the local copy of the file has an older time stamp than that of the file's time stamp on `x`. That means, it should download a file from a given location, only if there is a newer version of the file.

In case there is a newer version of the file, `wget` should overwrite the file.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Without being able to give a complete solution: do a 'man wget' and look for the --no-clobber options.

Comment: But what is "time stamp"? The remote file timestamp or local file timestamp?

Comment: Check the local one with the remote one (timestamp)

Comment: But the remote file has not a real timestamp. 
You can check if different using an MD5 hash for example but not more recent or not.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for the TimeStamping functionality of wget: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping

> Say you would like to download a file
>   so that it keeps its date of
>   modification.

```
wget -S http://www.gnu.ai.mit.edu/
```

> A simple ls -l shows that the time stamp on the local file equals the state of the
>   Last-Modified header, as returned by
>   the server. As you can see, the
>   time-stamping info is preserved
>   locally, even without ‘-N’ (at least
>   for http).
>
> Several days later, you would like
>   Wget to check if the remote file has
>   changed, and download it if it has.

```
wget -N http://www.gnu.ai.mit.edu/
```

Comment: If you are downloading a complex web page then it is NOT clear to me if you can check if the remote file has changed or not (or is it) with the CMD `wget -N --tries=3 --output-document=latest_obs.txt --no-check-certificate --save-cookies=cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data="usr=admin.admin&pwd=password" https://192.168.1.1:8030/_LOGIN_SERVER_RSP_`

Comment: --output-document is not compatible with --timestamping

Comment: wget -N returns 0 whether it downloaded the file or not (found no newer file). What would be the easiest way to detect if the file was actually downloaded?

Comment: @SoichiHayashi: why would it matter?

Comment: @MestreLion I'm looking for the same thing. Can't speak for SoichiHayashi, but I want to combine time-stamping with the logrotate-style versioning. However it looks like the easiest way to do that will be parsing wget's output, instead of getting to rely on a return code representing e.g. fetched / not-fetched.

Comment: While `-N --output-document=filename` is incompatible, it works with `-c --output-document=filename` to reach the same effect.

Comment: Thank you. At least in Ubuntu, the `man` page doesn't explain what `--timestamping` does.

Comment: @mgutt that --continue trick works like a charm, thank you!